# SQL Server Reporting Services 2017: Multiple Instances

Tags: installation, ssrs-2017, ssrs-2019

SQL Server Reporting Services are no longer part of the installation media since SQL Server 2017. They are delivered as a [separate Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55252).

The new [Installation Wizard](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5237/installing-sql-server-reporting-services-2017/) gives no option to install multiple (named) instances of SSRS 2017 on the same machine.

Is that still possible?

Comment: This question is/was also valid for SQL Server 2019 Reporting Services, as the product does not support multi-instance installations and configuration. This comes with a hefty price-tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my research, this is currently not implemented in SSRS 2017. I was not able to find any information in an official `Deprecated Features` document.

- [Comment from user 'Matt'](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlrsteamblog/2017/10/02/sql-server-2017-reporting-services-now-generally-available/#comments)
- [Comment from user 'Sai_Kumar'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/install-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Twitter-Post from Christopher Finlan](https://twitter.com/cmfinlan/status/981703484138377216), Senior Program Manager, Power BI Report Server & SQL Server Reporting Services at Microsoft.

I found two votes to bring this functionality back to the product:

- [Support Power BI Report Server multiple instances on a single server](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19685863-support-power-bi-report-server-multiple-instances)
- [Restore multiple instance support for Reporting services in SQL 2017](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33212713-restore-multiple-instance-support-for-reporting-se)

Update (May 2019): [The feature will not be reimplemented](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19685863-support-power-bi-report-server-multiple-instances)

> AdminChris Finlan (Program Manager, Microsoft Power BI) replied:
>
> Hi all, We aren’t planning to re-implement multi-instance support as
>   we had prior to SSRS 2017. We recommend using virtualization as an
>   alternative, and we’re also looking at possibly adding container
>   support in the future.

Comment: The answer is equally valid for SQL Server 2019 Reporting Services. I can confirm that multi-instance installation are not provided in the installation routine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anyone working on this project has ever worked in the real world.  Let's say I own a court management system software company.  I have feature 'X' that I have released out to my customers.  Feature 'X' is actually a decent product and a clear gateway for selling other products my company sells.

Now, without warning and clear justification I rip the product out and let my User's stumble on to the problem.  Of course, I haven't notified my support staff and have not prepared documentation for working around the problem (just to add salt to the wound I will have one of my pompous dev managers throw around words like virtualization and container.)

Then, when cornered, I blurt out "It will be added back in ..." wait a year and then blurt out "it won't be added in."  Only a truly blind monopoly could get away with such actions.  Microsoft, your arrogance and lack of professionalism in this matter is astonishing.  You should lead us forward not into the gutter.